# Arduino Mega 2560 from .org- which IDE works?

Tags: arduino-mega, ide

My personal choice is to purchase from the .cc (or adafruit) for new boards. YMMV.  Craigslist locally of course has generic and .org boards now and then.

If I get a .org board on craigslist, will I need to use their fork of the IDE for the board to be recognized by the IDE?

My feeling is "yes" but I wanted to confirm.

A board there just now is Arduino mega 2560 from the .org.  Would I have to use their flavor of the IDE?

Thank you for your thoughts- photo of the board I am considering is attached.

[image: CL mega2560]

Comment: Have you compared the schematics yet?

Comment: Yes, That doesn't look different that I can see.
I was thinking more about the IDE6 not recognizing the vendor or board ID due to all the things going on between .cc and .org.

Comment: Then you can use any IDE you like as long as you use the appropriate firmware.

Comment: Perfect timing on your reply, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino.org and arduino.cc have come to a agreement.
As such all incompatibilities that exist (I don't think they exist for this mega board) will be solved with next version of the Arduino IDE as if it is a board of their own.